# JavaScript: How to delete 2 columns from 5D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am having a 5D array as below:

```
var array = [
    ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
    ["10", "9", "8", "7", "6"],
    ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]
];
```

I want to have an array like this:

```
var array = [
    ["1", "2", "5"],
    ["10", "9", "6"],
    ["11", "12", "15"]
];
```

Basically I want to remove column 2 and 3.

For 1D array [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) works perfectly fine but I don`t know how to remove multiple columns from a 5D array.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see 2D array... O:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use splice on every item of the array:

```js
var array = [
    ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
    ["10", "9", "8", "7", "6"],
    ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]
];
array.forEach(function (a) {
    a.splice(2, 2);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: can't do better nice answer!

Comment: @VicJordan, `a` is declared  in the callback. please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach for more information. does your error appears here on this site?